# Bind combobox with data from database

Tags: c#, winforms

I had windows form and I added combobox which bin data from database I added my code but this error apeared (invalid column name Category) altought the name was right .

```
public Category()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CategoryParent();
}

private void CategoryParent()
{
    using (SqlConnection Con = GetConnection())
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Category.Category,Category.Id from Category", Con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        CBParent.DataSource = dt;
        CBParent.DisplayMember = "Category";
        CBParent.ValueMember = "Id";
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you execute the SQL `Select Category.Category,Category.Id from Category` inside your preferred SQL tool? *Personally* I think the *query* is the problem - perhaps due to case-sensitivity on the column name, or a typo.

Comment: when you run this is Managemenet Studio , what are the column names in the resut ? are they the same as in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query like this,

```
   Select Category.Category as CatName ,Category.Id from Category
```

i-e use an alias like "CatName" for your column and set Display member like this,

```
      CBParent.DisplayMember = "CatName";
```

Hope it shall help.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the connection and I found the connectionstring was wrong